# Divide and Conquer Delaunay Triangulation - Getting first (aka "base") edge while merging

Tags: algorithm, geometry, delaunay

I'm trying to implement the Divide and Conquer algorithm for Delaunay Triangulation found [here](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~samuelp/del_project.html), but I've run into a problem. When merging two sets, I'm supposed to find the bottom-most edge between them, that doesn't intersect any of the edges already in the graph.

My first problem is, that bottom-most is not defined at all and it's not obvious. A lot of texts, I've read, say, that the edge between the vertices with the lowest y values in the two sets can be safely used, but this is not the case, as seen on this image:
[image]

I'm pretty sure, that at least one of these points must be part of that edge, but I can't prove it anyhow.

I don't want to check every pair of edges against the graphs, because for larger data sets, that might take too long.

So I'm looking for a way of finding this base edge. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure, I just figured it out. After getting the vertices with the lowest y values, I ran through both of the sets and looked for the two vertices, that are under the line (or on it) formed by the previously selected vertices and have the largest distances from it. If two points have the same distance form the line, I took the one with the largest x value in the case of the left set and the lowest in the case of the right.

This seems to work pretty well. This is because I noticed that, in order for an intersection to happen, there needs to be a point under that line, that is part of the edge intersecting our base edge. This way, I think I found the lowest edge tangent to both of the sets, meaning, that if I rotate this set, so this line is horizontal, there exists no points below it.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. Another tip is to read the original paper rather than a description in undergrad's term project, excellent though it may be.

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestion and it doesn't work. Here's an example of this approach failing -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyip8.png

The two red points are the bottom-most vertices from these two halves, and as you can see I'm taking the most distant ones to the base segment (in yellow). I think your only option here is to actually perform a segment intersection.

Comment: @Trap man, such an old thread.
What you could probably do is instead of the largest distance, look at the largest angle and use an iterative solution. There are 3 cases I see, you find a line and check, what points lie under it. Case 1. both sets have at least one point under the line, then I would pick the ones with the lowest y, though can't say why. The other 2 are that either side has points under it, then check the one with the largest angle from the possibilities and repeat from step 1 (not sure if necessary). Each iteration should get rid of points under the line, so it should end.

Comment: @GorbitGames Hey, thanks. I've been researching a bit and it's easier than it seems. Basically you start from the leftmost and rightmost vertices and from there you keep lowering the base segment until it makes a right turn wrt the connected LR segments (or a left turn, depending on the triangle winding order you're using).

Comment: @Trap should probably make an answer from that, I'll accept yours if you do

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up with following algorithm:

1. build convex hull using [Andrew's monotone chain algorithm](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain) .
2. get edges of the convex hull which are not in sub-triangulations convex hulls.
3. lowest of obtained edges is the required base edge.

Note about third step: segment `S1` is considered to be below another segment `S2` if orientation of `S2` (which endpoints are taken in ascending order by `x` coordinate) with both endpoints of `S1` is not counterclockwise, i.e. `S1` is never on the left side of `S2` if we are moving on `S2`.

[image: example of case when segment S2 is above segment S1]

## Time complexity notes

1. since in the beginning of the D&C algorithm we are sorting points lexicographically by `x` and then by `y`, building of the sub-triangulations convex hull will be `O(n)` (no sorting is needed), where `n` is the number of points in both sub-triangulations.
2. we can use containers with `O(1)` lookup (like hash tables) of sub-triangulations edges and filter out in `O(n)`.
3. searching for the lowest edge can be done in `O(n)`.

so overall process will require `O(n)` operations.